# Programming tableviews segue drill down

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, uistoryboard, segue

I am currently trying to convert my apps to Storyboards. My data is currently stored in a plist file and I drill down through my tableviews very easily using the following code in my current `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if ([children count] == 0)

{
    NSString *tempString1 = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Movie"];
    NSString *tempString2 = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Text"];
    NSString *tempString3 = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Diagram"];

    DetailsVC *dvc = [[DetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsVC" bundle:nil];

    dvc.movie = tempString1;
    dvc.pdfdesc = tempString2;
    dvc.pdfDiagram = tempString3;
    dvc.navigationItem.title = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Title"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

}
else

{

    LevelsVC *lvc = [[LevelsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LevelsVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    lvc.currentLevel += 1;
    lvc.navigationItem.title = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];

    lvc.tableDataSource = children;

    }
```

**My question is**: How on earth do I convert this method for use with Segues and Storyboards? I can easily create a segue for detailViews, and there are a million tutorials for that on the net, but i simply cannot figure out how to drill down through the data in my tableview.

Any help or sample code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to transition from one view controller to another programmatically. Just move the code that configures `dvc` to your `-prepareForSegue:sender:` implementation.

Another option is to connect your segue in the storyboard from a cell in the table to the next view controller. That will cause the segue to be triggered as soon as the row is selected, which prevents you from having to start the segue programmatically at all. In that case, you just implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:` to set any necessary data in the segue's destination view controller. The `sender` parameter will be the table cell that was tapped, and you can use that to find the selected row.

Comment: Should be 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'

Comment: @Caleb - The dvc code is not the one I'm stuck on, it is the LVC code. I don't know how to wire up the tableview so that the next set of data drills down. For instance, I want to go tabledata1 > tabledata2 > tabledata3 > DetailViewController. Can you please elaborate on how to do that? Your patience is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same idea -- replace your `-initWithNibName:...` call with `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and move the configuration code into `-prepareForSegue:sender:`. The former starts the segue and creates the new view controller, the latter gives you a chance to configure the new controller before its view becomes visible.

Comment: Ok @Caleb. I'll be back with a full report. Thanks a million for trying to help. I think I am making this infinitely more complicated than it needs to be. When I look at code I usually get it - I"m still working on understanding things conceptually. If I get it, I"ll put a full post up for all. I"m sure I can't be the only person to run into this!

Comment: @Caleb: I'm still confused -  Before, when using xib files, I just kept reusing LevelsVC in my didSelect: method until my plist ran out of data. Then I would pass data on to the DetailsVC and Xib file. I understand how to get to my detailView, but I still don't get _how I repopulate LevelsVC with the next set of drill down data_?  This is absolutely maddening. I want to navigate as follows: Levels VC (1) > Levels VC (2), Levels VC (3) and then Finally DetailsVC. Looking at my above code, do you undersand what I'd like to do with storyboards?