# Storyboards and Google maps ios SDK

Tags: storyboard, google-maps-sdk-ios

I wanted to know, how can I change to a different view that I created using Storyboard by clicking on a Google Map object ( marker for e.g) .
What I am trying to do is, when a user clicks on a marker representing a location on google maps, the app should now go to a different page where some details of the location will be displayed. I couldnot figure out the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` when the user taps on the marker. It's essentially the same situation that's covered in [Programming tableviews segue drill down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17711013/643383), except that you're using a map and that question uses a table.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement the `GMSMapViewDelegate` and set `mapView.delegate = self;`

Then use `-mapView:didTapMarker:` to listen to when someone taps a Marker

Then call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to load the new view